# How add foreign key on embed forms

Tags: forms, entity

I have 2 entities Patients

```
class Patients 
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

     /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="ContactAddress", mappedBy="patient" ,cascade={"persist"})
     */
    protected $contactaddress;
```

And ContactAddress

```
class ContactAddress
{
     /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Patients", inversedBy="contactaddress")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="patient_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
     protected $patient;
}
```

I did embed form It almost worked but only field patient_id is NULL. I want id from Patients will be foreign key in ContactAddress 
A part of my controller

```
   $entity  = new Patients();
   $request = $this->getRequest();
   $form    = $this->createForm(new \Surgery\PatientBundle\Form\PatientsType(), $entity);
   $form->bindRequest($request);

    if($request->getMethod()=='POST')  //sending form
    {
        if ($form->isValid())  //valid form
        {        
            $em->persist($entity);               
            $em->flush();  

            return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('kategoria_show', array('id' => $entity->getId())));  


        }
```

edit: 
I changed associations

```
 /**
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Patients", inversedBy="patients")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="patient_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
 protected $patient;



 /**
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="ContactAddress", mappedBy="contactaddress" ,cascade={"persist"})
 */
protected $contactaddress;
```

But It's still not works, My field patient_id in ContactAddress is NULL

Answer (score 0):

I think you might have your owning vs inverse sides mixed up.

> "The owning side of a OneToOne association is the entity with the table containing the foreign key." —[Doctrine Documentation Chapter 11](https://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/unitofwork-associations.html)